# Calculate percent change in a column within a group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My dataframe has a Ticker column and a Price column.  There are 10 rows per Ticker (with the same Ticker value) but each row has a different Price.

My aim is to calculate the percent change within a Ticker group.

I tried the following but failed:

```
Test_preds_actual1['Target1_preds_pct_chng'] = 0
Test_preds_actual1.groupby('Ticker')['Target1_preds_pct_chng'] =\
Test_preds_actual1.groupby('Ticker')['Target1_preds'].pct_change()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-316-168796f850f9> in <module>
      1 Test_preds_actual1.groupby('Ticker')['Target1_preds_pct_chng'] =\
----> 2 Test_preds_actual1.groupby('Ticker')['Target1_preds'].pct_change()

TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment
```

I am not sure I understand the error message.  How can I accomplish my objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do assign

```
Test_preds_actual1['Target1_preds_pct_chng']=Test_preds_actual1.groupby('Ticker')['Target1_preds'].pct_change()
```